# How do I check the content of ()

Tags: ios, swift

Currently I'm using alamofire to fetch data from the server. The API will return either

My goal is to check whether the data is empty or not

Empty bracket

```
[()]
```

or will return

```
[(
  {
    "name": "joker",
    "age": 12,  
  }

)]
```

if I do `data[0]` then it will show `()`, how do i check if the `()` is empty or have data

Comment: @Wez check the latest question

Comment: @sinusBog please show some more code, what does the Alamofire request/response look like? This currently just looks like a JSON string.

Comment: That's not JSON, that's strange (the presence of `()`). In theory, `data[0]` should be a Dictionary, then `data[0].isEmpty` or something like that should do the trick.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check an array of 'Any' type if it is empty or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46341245/how-to-check-an-array-of-any-type-if-it-is-empty-or-not)

Answer (score 0):

**If** yu are sure your data will be enclosed within [()], you can simply trim the string

```
let trimmedString = dataString.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "[()]"))
```

and check if the trimmedString is empty.

Comment: Check this question instead, sorry for wasting your time instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46341245/how-to-check-an-array-of-any-type-if-it-is-empty-or-not

Answer (score 0):

Just use data.count to check empty. I think you used `po` in console, it will print extra ().

Comment: po? what is that?

Answer (score 0):

When your data is empty, i.e. `[()]`, then `data.count` will return `1` because it contains a `single element that is empty`.

To check for if the contained element is also empty, you can use:

```
data.first?.isEmpty
```

**`isEmpty`** can be used on any `sequence type`. It returns `true` is the sequence is empty, and `false` otherwise.

Comment: the `data` is an `Any` type. I can't use first?

Comment: Then what does () specify?

Comment: Check this question instead, sorry for wasting your time instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46341245/how-to-check-an-array-of-any-type-if-it-is-empty-or-not

Answer (score 0):

It seems not a valid JSON

Anyways try this:

```
    /// <dataResponse> is your response sting...
    let charSet = CharacterSet.init(charactersIn: "[()]")
    let trimmedString = dataResposne.trimmingCharacters(in: charSet)
    if trimmedString.isEmpty {
        /// Empty Response
    }
    else    {
        /// Non Emtpy Response
    }
```

Comment: check this question instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46341245/how-to-check-an-array-of-any-type-if-it-is-empty-or-not