# How to check an array of 'Any' type if it is empty or not?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using socket.io to get the data and right now it returns an Array of `'Any'` object

**The code**

```
socket.on("listeningOnSomething") { data, ack in
   // data is an array of Any Type
}
```

I tried to do

```
socket.on("listeningOnSomething") { data, ack in
       if (data[0].isEmpty?) { // Keep giving me error that 'Any' object has no isEmpty? object

       }
}
```

The result of the data if

it is empty

```
[()]
```

if it is not empty

```
[(

{
   name: "batman",
   age: "47"
}
)]
```

Comment: You need to tell the compiler that `data[0]` is a Dictionary, and then allowed to use `isEmpty`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to cast `data[0]` to a dictionary of type `[String: Any]`:

```
if (data[0] as? [String: Any])?.isEmpty ?? true {
  ...
}
```

or better *(and safer because of using `.first` over `[0]`)*:

```
if let dictionary = data.first as? [String: Any], dictionary.isEmpty {
  ...
}
```

Comment: You should use `.first` instead of `[0]`

Comment: I received type Any does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'.

Comment: I used the second method because it is safer.